# Passing arrays in MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Okay so this is a bit complicated but I will try to explain it as simple as possible.

I have a Model class which does all the activity and stores information in arrays.

I have a Controller class which makes a new Model class and calls required action from Model class to perform the activity.

But all that has to happen from a View file. So I submit a form from my View file, refresh the page and upon refresh, my Controller class checks if the form has been submitted or not, if true then it starts creating an object from my Model class.

Now, here's the part I am having problem. I again need to redirect the page within the Controller class, basically what it is doing is upon refresh it is actually calling the action within the Controller class itself according to data being sent by the Model class. e.g

In my Controller class there is a constructor that creates a new Model object calls Model action and has if and else statement to check for the data being sent by Model class.

Now, based on the value it calls/redirects to my two other action in Controller class. But as I redirect using

```
    header("model/controller/");
```

my arrays are lost and there is no way I can pass my arrays from Controller to the View.

I have tried

```
    header("model/controller/".$array);
```

and passing it through urls. But I would rather not pass it through urls.

So is it even possible to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Also, sorry if this might be a naive question or a very bad programming practice, I'm just learning. Critiques are very much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is *How to persist data between two HTTP requests*, and the answer is usually to use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). It has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: I said that because of the way Model, View and Controller behave with each other. I would not have this problem in the first place if it was not for the separation of files. But yes, I did think of sessions too which is why I am trying to avoid because the simplified framework that we have deals with session in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to pass it like that is to use

```
$data = implode('/',$array);
header("model/controller/".$data);
```

and when receiving them, in your model use this code:

```
$data = explode('/',fun_get_args());
// OR
$data = explode('/',$requestURL);
// $requestURL to be replaced with a function depending on your MVC
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I'll go ahead and test the code and let you know on how it goes.

Comment: I have got it working :) albeit in a different approach but the idea was basically the same. Instead of '/' I used ';' because / is treated specially in our MVC. 
Thanks for the tip. ^_^